# Visual studio keeps switching back to git source control provider

Tags: visual-studio

I don't want VS to fiddle with git, I use sourcetree for that, so I set the source control provider in the tools -> options -> source control to none.

As soon as you open a project that has git versioning on it the setting automatically switches back to git source control provider.

How to permanantly disable it?

I'm using visual studio 2013 update 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found an answer in a blog:

http://researchaholic.com/2015/02/02/remove-the-microsoft-gitprovider-from-visual-studio-2013/

To remove the git provider altogether one can delete the key

```
11b8e6d7-c08b-4385-b321-321078cdd1f8
```

from the registry via regedit:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\SourceControlProviders
```

note that you completely remove it, so only for people not interested in a CPU eating annoying ms-plugin.

Comment: The git provider isn't any more "CPU eating" than git itself. If you have issues, you should check the other plugins installed. In the linked article's case, the poster is using a VM that doesn't handle Windows paravirtualization well so git itself or SourceTree would be just as slow. The delay just isn't as noticeable outside the IDE

Comment: It's the git source control provider. Visual studio is eating +/- 20% all the time when it's switched on. Look elsewhere on this issue, many people have it.

Comment: Second Elger's comment. Git plugin is killing Visual Studio on some projects.

Comment: Unfortunately, the registry just keeps coming back in VS 2015 SP2

Answer (score 2):

I found that I had this problem, even for projects that have never had anything to do with git.  It started when I initialized a git repo in my `C:\Users\<username>` directory, and it went away wen I deleted the `.git\` folder from that repo.

Answer (score 1):

I also found it does this, if you keep all of your source code in one base folder (in my case D:\Source).  I have my TFS "root" mapped to D:\Source<project name>.  As it turns out, I downloaded some sample Xamarin project from Microsoft using git & started in the D:\Source\ folder, which created the D:\Source.git folder.  After creating this folder, it assumed anything that was a peer/sibling to that folder was a git repo.

Deleting this .git folder in my TFS path fixed it for me.